# Increment Every record with hundred (incrementally depends on row number) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a select statement to generate view like

```
select 0||trim(TO_CHar(max(macode)+100,99999999)) 
from view;
```

macode values like

Maccode

```
020500
020500
033200
033200
033200
033200
```

But I want to increment every macode value with 100. I want result like this:

Maccode

```
020500+100 = 020600;
020500+200 = 020700;
033200+300 = 020800;
033200+400 = 020900;
```

That means every previous record increment with 100.

How can I generate this view without using any sequence?

Comment: `+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Maccode) * 100`

Comment: The query you are showing results in one row only (the maximum macode + 100). But you want to select all existing macodes + n*100 instead? Do you want to apply an order or doesn't it matter which macode gets +100 and which, say, +400?

Answer (score 1):

Use query as follow. Works 100% :

```
    select lpad(TO_NUMBER(macode) + (100 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Maccode)), 6, '0') from view;
```

Here is Example :

```
select macode Before, lpad(TO_NUMBER(macode) + (100 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY macode)), 6, '0')  After from
     (
        select '020500' macode from dual
        UNION ALL 
        select '020500' macode from dual
        UNION ALL 
        select '033200' macode from dual
        UNION ALL 
        select '033200' macode from dual
        UNION ALL 
        select '033200' macode from dual
        UNION ALL 
        select '033200' macode from dual
      )
```

And this is how  result looks:

```
BEFORE  AFTER
020500  020600
020500  020700
033200  033500
033200  033600
033200  033700
033200  033800
```

Comment: Sir, if i use:0||trim(TO_CHar(max(macode)+(100 * max(ROWNUM)),99999999))

Comment: error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: there is no max expression in my query

Comment: use max:   lpad(TO_NUMBER(max(macode)) + (100 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY macode)), 6, '0')  error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: @bab Look query and ouput ,Works 100%

Comment: Sir, dual working fine but using view  use lpad(TO_NUMBER(macode) + (100 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Maccode)), 6, '0') getting error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: @bab: Where's the `MAX` coming from, it's not in your query? If you actually need it you must modify it to: `+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Max(Maccode)) * 100`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add 100 in your query like

```
select 0||(TO_NUMBER(trim(TO_CHar(max(macode),99999999)))+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Maccode) * 100) from view;
```

Here `TO_NUMBER()` will convert the value into integer and after that you can add 100 or any other number `TO_NUMBER(trim(TO_CHar(max(macode),99999999)))**+100**`

Comment: But i need auto increment,  first value add with 100 and second value with 200 and third value with 300 etc..

Comment: try modified query